# java- search .txt file for list of values

Tags: java

I'm fairly new to Java and I'm trying to tackle something that I know should be possible, but I can't wrap my head around how to accomplish it.

I have successfully opened/imported a text file (example below) but now need to scan the entire document for the Source=  tag; returning all of the unique values into a list that will be used in another method.  So for this example I need a list of (Net, Local, Remote).

Can anyone suggest how this could be accomplished?

```
!4542424
type="Home"Source=""Name="Jim"
information about first record
type="Away"Source="Net"Name="Sue"
information about second record
type="Work"Source="Local"Name="Ted"
information about third record
type="Work"Source=""Name="Mark"
information about fourth record
type="Home""Source="Net"Name="Josh"
information about fifth record
type="Home"Source="Remote"Name="Joe"
information about sixth record
```

Comment: What have you tried? What are you struggling to wrap your head around? There are *countless* questions on SO about reading from files and processing their contents.

Comment: It is possible - you can find many examples online of how to read text files in Java, and how to parse them for content. In your example, it's enough to read each line and look for "source=" in it, then take the value after it into a list - if it's not already in the list.

Comment: I have been able to successfully open the file iterate through each line.  (writing them to console to verify that was working)   I can't figure out how to capture the characters between the quotes after source= to add them to a list though.

Comment: So you need to clearly mention that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be great to know what you actually tried doing. But to help you in the right direction anyways, try reading about [BufferedReader example](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/) and [StringTokenizer example](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-split-a-string/).

Comment: Or just [`Files.readAllLines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-)

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at these examples.  I think split may work, I just didn't know if that was the best method knowing that there will be many many duplicate source entries.   The text file typically has 4-10,000 lines each day and only 30-35 unique source values.